# unable to validate form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am unable to think the logic & implement it at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7TMrc/3/)

**Problem Is:**
It should allow the form to be submitted if at-least one text-box(out of 2 i.e HR & Min) validation goes to true...

eg. if i enter "1" in Min textbox & click submit then it should submit the form because 1 is valid min & vice versa 
but in my case it only submitting form if both text-box values goes to true

jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.fn.SubmitForm = function(id) {  //submit the form 

        var hour = $("#time-hr-id" + id).val();
        var mins = $("#time-min-id" + id).val();

        if (isNaN(hour) || hour > 24 || hour < 0.1) {
            var error_msg = 'Hour:Not a valid value';
            alert(error_msg);
            $("#time-hr-id" + id).focus();
        } else if(isNaN(mins) || mins > 60 || mins < 0.1) {
            var error_msg = 'Mins:Not a valid value';
            alert(error_msg);
            $("#time-min-id" + id).focus();
        } else {
            $("#formid" + id).submit();
        }
    };
});
```

Html Code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped TF" style="width: 100%;" id="table6">
<tbody>
<tr class="fltrow">
    <td>
        <input id="flt0_table6" type="hidden" ct="0" class="flt">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="flt1_table6" type="hidden" ct="1" class="flt">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="flt2_table6" type="hidden" ct="2" class="flt">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="flt3_table6" type="hidden" ct="3" class="flt">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="flt4_table6" type="hidden" ct="4" class="flt">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="flt5_table6" type="hidden" ct="5" class="flt">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="flt6_table6" type="hidden" ct="6" class="flt">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="flt7_table6" type="hidden" ct="7" class="flt">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="success">
    <td style="width: 15%;">
        S.no
    </td>
    <td style="width: 15%;">
        Activity <br>
         Name
    </td>
    <td style="width: 5%;">
        Activity Option
    </td>
    <td style="width: 5%;">
        Duration<br>
         HR:MIN
    </td>
    <td style="width:10%;">
        cals
    </td>
    <td style="width: 5%;">
        distance
    </td>
    <td style="width: 5%;">
        Unit
    </td>
    <td style="width: 15%;">
        Submit
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="formrowid228" style="display: none;">
    <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid228">
    </form>
    <td style="width:5%;">
        1
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <a href="http://localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/228/227">sitting - card playing, playing board games</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <div style="display:inline-flex;">
            <input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id228" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" value="" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(228);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(228);" id="time-min-id228" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id228" value="1.5"><span id="cals-id228" class="cals">0.00</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <button onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(228);" class="btn btn-success activity-btn" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="formrowid229" style="display: none;">
    <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid229">
    </form>
    <td style="width:5%;">
        2
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <a href="http://localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/229/227">standing - drawing (writing), casino gambling, duplicating machine</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <div style="display:inline-flex;">
            <input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id229" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" value="" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(229);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(229);" id="time-min-id229" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id229" value="2.3"><span id="cals-id229" class="cals">0.00</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <button onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(229);" class="btn btn-success activity-btn" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="formrowid230" style="display: none;">
    <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid230">
    </form>
    <td style="width:5%;">
        3
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <a href="http://localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/230/227">sitting - reading, book, newspaper, etc.</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <div style="display:inline-flex;">
            <input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id230" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" value="" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(230);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(230);" id="time-min-id230" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id230" value="1.3"><span id="cals-id230" class="cals">0.00</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <button onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(230);" class="btn btn-success activity-btn" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="formrowid231" style="display: none;">
    <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid231">
    </form>
    <td style="width:5%;">
        4
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <a href="http://localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/231/227">sitting - writing, desk work, typing</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <div style="display:inline-flex;">
            <input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id231" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" value="" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(231);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(231);" id="time-min-id231" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id231" value="1.8"><span id="cals-id231" class="cals">0.00</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <button onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(231);" class="btn btn-success activity-btn" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="formrowid232" style="display: none;">
    <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid232">
    </form>
    <td style="width:5%;">
        5
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <a href="http://localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/232/227">standing - talking or talking on the phone</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <div style="display:inline-flex;">
            <input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id232" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" value="" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(232);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(232);" id="time-min-id232" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id232" value="1.8"><span id="cals-id232" class="cals">0.00</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <button onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(232);" class="btn btn-success activity-btn" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="formrowid233" style="display: none;">
    <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid233">
    </form>
    <td style="width:5%;">
        6
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <a href="http://localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/233/227">sitting - talking or talking on the phone</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <div style="display:inline-flex;">
            <input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id233" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" value="" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(233);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(233);" id="time-min-id233" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id233" value="1.5"><span id="cals-id233" class="cals">0.00</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <button onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(233);" class="btn btn-success activity-btn" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="formrowid234" style="display: none;">
    <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid234">
    </form>
    <td style="width:5%;">
        7
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <a href="http://localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/234/227">sitting - studying, general, including reading and/or writing</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <div style="display:inline-flex;">
            <input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id234" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" value="" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(234);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(234);" id="time-min-id234" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id234" value="1.8"><span id="cals-id234" class="cals">0.00</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <button onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(234);" class="btn btn-success activity-btn" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="formrowid235" style="display: none;">
    <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid235">
    </form>
    <td style="width:5%;">
        8
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <a href="http://localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/235/227">sitting - in class, general, including note-taking or class discussion</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <div style="display:inline-flex;">
            <input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id235" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" value="" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(235);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(235);" id="time-min-id235" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id235" value="1.8"><span id="cals-id235" class="cals">0.00</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <button onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(235);" class="btn btn-success activity-btn" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="formrowid236" style="display: none;">
    <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid236">
    </form>
    <td style="width:5%;">
        9
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <a href="http://localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/236/227">standing - reading</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <div style="display:inline-flex;">
            <input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id236" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" value="" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(236);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(236);" id="time-min-id236" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id236" value="1.8"><span id="cals-id236" class="cals">0.00</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <button onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(236);" class="btn btn-success activity-btn" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="formrowid237" style="display: none;">
    <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid237">
    </form>
    <td style="width:5%;">
        10
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <a href="http://localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/237/227">standing - miscellaneous</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <div style="display:inline-flex;">
            <input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id237" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" value="" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(237);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(237);" id="time-min-id237" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id237" value="2.0"><span id="cals-id237" class="cals">0.00</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <button onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(237);" class="btn btn-success activity-btn" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="formrowid243">
    <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid243">
    </form>
    <td style="width:5%;">
        1
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <a href="http://localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/243/227">running</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <div style="display:inline-flex;">
            <input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id243" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" value="" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(243);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(243);" id="time-min-id243" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id243" value="1.5"><span id="cals-id243" class="cals">0.00</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
         <input  onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(243);"  type="button" value='submit'/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="formrowid245">
    <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid245">
    </form>
    <td style="width:5%;">
        2
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <a href="http://localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/245/227">Dancing</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <div style="display:inline-flex;">
            <input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id245" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" value="" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(245);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(245);" id="time-min-id245" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id245" value="2.5"><span id="cals-id245" class="cals">0.00</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
         <input  onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(245);"  type="button" value='submit'/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="formrowid246">
    <form method="post" action="/tbft/webapp/logs/insertAcitivity" id="formid246">
    </form>
    <td style="width:5%;">
        3
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <a href="localhost/tbft/webapp/index.php/logs/activity/246/227">Playing</a>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:15%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <div style="display:inline-flex;">
            <input maxlength="2" id="time-hr-id246" name="timeHrTxt" size="2" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" value="" onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(246);" placeholder=" HR"> : <input onkeyup="$(this).CalculateCalorie(246);" id="time-min-id246" name="timeMinTxt" placeholder=" MIN" type="text" style="width:35px;text-align:center;" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="metsTxt" id="mets-id246" value="1.5"><span id="cals-id246" class="cals">0.00</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        -
    </td>
    <td style="width:5%;" class="text-capitalize">
        <input  onclick="$(this).SubmitForm(246);"  type="button" value='submit'/>

        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: TypeError: $(...).CalculateCalorie is not a function is apperaring while i try to enter something.. Do u restrict  any key in keypress event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo here -- http://jsfiddle.net/7TMrc/7/

Key things:

The val() function returns a string, so if the length of the hours or mins variable is zero, then it is blank.

We consider blank to be OK if a blank minute is accompanied by a valid hour, or a blank hour is accompanied by a valid minute.

If the length of either the hour or minute is more than zero, we check it is a valid hour or minute, and parseFloat is helpful here.

We do the validity checking first ("have we got valid hours and mins?") and then we do the logic of whether or not you can submit ("have I got at least a valid hour or a valid minute?").

```
              $.fn.SubmitForm = function(id) {  //submit the form 

                // These will be strings  
                var hour = $("#time-hr-id" + id).val();
                var mins = $("#time-min-id" + id).val();

                // Assume they are valid
                var valid_hour = true;
                var valid_mins = true;

                // If the hour string is not blank, see if the hour is valid using parseFloat 
                if (hour.length > 0 && isNaN(hour) || parseFloat(hour) > 24 || parseFloat(hour) < 0.1) {
                    valid_hour = false;
                }

                // If the mins string is not blank, see if the min is valid using parseFloat          
                if(mins.length > 0 && isNaN(mins) || parseFloat(mins) > 60 || parseFloat(mins) < 0.1) {
                    valid_mins = false;
                }

                // Now we can do the submit logic more easily. valid_hour and valid_minute
                // will only be false if bad data, not blank data, has been entered.             
                if (!valid_hour) {
                    var error_msg = 'Hour:Not a valid value';
                    alert(error_msg);
                    $("#time-hr-id" + id).focus();
                } else if(!valid_mins) {
                    var error_msg = 'Mins:Not a valid value';
                    alert(error_msg);
                    $("#time-min-id" + id).focus();
                // We have a new test case - we need to ensure that both are not blank!
                } else if (hour == "" & mins == "") {
                    var error_msg = 'Empty mins and hours!';
                    alert(error_msg);
                    $("#time-hr-id" + id).focus();      
                } else {
                    $("#formid" + id).submit();
                }

            };
```

Comment: Thanks chaps! No, I didn't see Sid M's answer until I posted this. He's got some of what I've done, but I think the useful thing is splitting it into two stages: first, if I have data, is my data valid? then second, have I got enough data to submit?

Comment: disabling the button onclick & enabling it after showing alert is not working it seems. can you check on your fiddle

Comment: There's no code in your original fiddle for disabling and enabling the button? I think this is a separate issue - maybe you could open a new question for it?

Comment: hmm! Add a disable & enable button in your fiddle only that all... if i add again similier question then it will became spam..  http://jsfiddle.net/7TMrc/8/    << i added here disable & enabling lines but it does not show effect